# Question about passage in search algorithm chapter, Nielsen-Chuang

Tags: grovers-algorithm

I'd like to ask how to get to the final line of equation 6.22, I wonder about the cos and sin functions in particular. (page 257 Nielsen-Chuang) [image]

Comment: See Exercises 4.2 and 4.4 of N&C. If you are stuck, see [my solutions manual](https://github.com/jacobwatkins1/Nielsen-and-Chuang-Solutions), but try to do as much yourself as possible. If you find this exercise quite confusing it may benefit you to revisit Ch 2.

Comment: If this satisfies you, I might suggest closing your question. As you can see it is not really a question about search as much as qubit operations.